# How to transform Lambda function output as input for Choice state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have just started exploring AWS step functions & I'm trying to create a state machine that invokes a Lambda function to generate random integers. The state machine then uses the Lambda function output in a Choice state to determine the execution flow.

For example, if the Lambda function generates a number < 10, the Choice state moves to a Fail state. If the Lambda function generates a number > 10, the Choice state moves to a Pass state and workflow execution completes.

Error:
`The choice state's condition path references an invalid value.`

```json
{
  "Comment": "An example of input output processing",
  "StartAt": "getScore",
  "States": {
    "getScore": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:***:function:random-num",
      "ResultPath": "$.result",
      "OutputPath": "$.result",
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 3,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "checkScoreValue"
    },
    "checkScoreValue": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.result.latest",
          "NumericLessThan": 40,
          "Next": "Fail"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.result.latest",
          "NumericGreaterThan": 41,
          "Next": "Pass"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Pass"
    },
    "Pass": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "You have passed",
      "End": true
    },
    "Fail": {
      "Type": "Fail",
      "Cause": "You have failed!"
    }
  }
}
```

Error:
`An error occurred while executing the state 'checkScoreValue' (entered at the event id #7). Invalid path '$.result.latest': The choice state's condition path references an invalid value.`

Lambda function code:

```js
exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
    const randNumber = Math.floor( 50 * Math.random() );
    return randNumber;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What does your function return if you test the function via the console? Can you please add the output to your question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're not accessing or modifying the state output correctly throughout this step function, resulting in the error of `Invalid path '$.result.latest'`.**

---

Your Lambda has a sample output of `29`, which isn't within a JSON object.

And since you don't have any state input, your `ResultPath` value becomes invalid - there is no state input, and thus no root `$` object to add your Lambda result into.

Your `OutputPath` value also becomes invalid - there is no JSON output at all to filter from.

So, first remove `ResultPath` & `OutputPath` from your state machine.

Now with the output of `29`, your Choice state is still trying to access `$.result.latest` which simply does not exist.

There is no JSON object to use the `result.latest` JSON path so just pass the entire output - the number - through by changing `Variable` from `$.result.latest` to `$`.

This works for me:

```json
{
  "Comment": "An example of input output processing",
  "StartAt": "getScore",
  "States": {
    "getScore": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:***:function:random-num",
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 3,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "checkScoreValue"
    },
    "checkScoreValue": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$",
          "NumericLessThan": 40,
          "Next": "Fail"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$",
          "NumericGreaterThan": 41,
          "Next": "Pass"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Pass"
    },
    "Pass": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "You have passed",
      "End": true
    },
    "Fail": {
      "Type": "Fail",
      "Cause": "You have failed!"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ermiya. Thank you so much for the detailed response. I am now able to run my state machine, and also understand about input output processing in Step Functions a bit more. Thanks a lot!